# Admin Access Disabled

Tags: windows-7, uac

I have an Asus Laptop running Windows 7 64 bit. When I booted the computer today it showed two user account options. One was mine, the other was "Other User". Logged in as normal but I tried to do something that required admin rights. So the UAC pops up as expected but the "Yes" button has been disabled. I cannot do anything that requires admin rights. I have to to edit the registry to disable the UAC but again my account has lost trust on the machine.

[image]

Comment: Log into the built in Administrator account and fix your permissions on the user account you normally use.

Comment: This is on the built in admin account

Comment: A screenshot that lists the all your user accounts would be helpful.

Comment: I only have one user account.

Comment: I would still like the screenshot to confirm that.

Comment: I will get you a screenshot in a few hours when I get home from work.

Comment: Sorry my reputation is not high enough to post an image yet.

Comment: So use a comment instead.  I will include the screenshot for you.

Comment: ![Screen shot of user account control panel][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/ejhGO.png

Comment: Screenshot shows Zero user accounts why?

Comment: Wish I knew. This is all somehow related but, I can eliminate the virus idea as I have been able to scan it with a few tools and all have the same results of a clean system.

Comment: I could not find a solution for this issue so I did the only logical thing left. Completely deleted everything and started with a fresh install of Windows. Fortunately I am one of those people that have regular backups.